# Create vertical form elements inside an inline form in Bootstrap 3.3.6

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to create a bootstrap form with multiple horizontal and vertical elements but couldn't get what I wanted

**Requirement**

- Main `<form>` contains vertical `<formfield>` elements
- `<formfield>` element contain all elements horizontally
- `<formfield>` element has one `<div>` element that contain some vertical elements inside it

I have accomplished first two requirements without any issue but I'm clueless when it comes to last requirement.I've tried searching on google and stakoverflow but no luck yet.

**Needed form**
[image]

**Form I'm getting right now**
[image]

**My Code**

```html
<form id="grn_items_form">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <fieldset id="1" class="grn_item_fieldset ">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="form-control" id="1" class="remove_product" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="1" type="text" placeholder="Variation">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="1" type="text" placeholder="Unit Price">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="1" class="quantity" type="text" disabled="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="form-control" id="1" class="add_serial" type="button">Add Serials</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Serial Here">
          <a class="form-control remove_field" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Serial Here">
          <a class="form-control remove_field" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Serial Here">
          <a class="form-control remove_field" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <fieldset id="2" class="grn_item_fieldset">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="form-control" id="2" class="remove_product" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="2" type="text" placeholder="Variation">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="2" type="text" placeholder="Unit Price">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control quantity" id="2" type="text" placeholder="Quantity">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
```

Any suggestion on right direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. It's not actually showing right on jsfiddle but try to copy the HTML and run local.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
 <form>
  <div class="row" id="row1">
   <fieldset>
    <div class="row" id="main">
     <div class="col-md-1">
      <button class="form-control" id="1" class="remove_product" type="button">
       <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
      </button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Variation">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Unit Price">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2"></div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <button class="form-control" id="1" class="add_serial" type="button">
       Add Serials
      </button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="col-md-10">
       <input class="form-control " type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Serial Here">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
       <a class="form-control remove_field" href="#"> D </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="sub1">
     <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
      <div class="col-md-10">
       <input class="form-control " type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Serial Here">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
       <a class="form-control remove_field" href="#"> D </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="sub1">
     <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
      <div class="col-md-10">
       <input class="form-control " type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Serial Here">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
       <a class="form-control remove_field" href="#"> D </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```